# Poco sockets and Unix fifo

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, poco, fifo

I am using Poco C++ framework and want to make an abstraction to work with network sockets and local unix fifo channels in common way: composing one list of "devices" for Poco::Net::Socket::select() to read data in the same thread. In POSIX I can compose such list because socket and fifo both have integer file descriptors which I can use with poll() or select().
Is it possible to implement Unix fifo so that it has Poco::Socket interface?

Comment: @Duck unfortunately, no. Some components of system already implemented with fifo interfaces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm coming up empty at the moment.  Everything I have thought about is a lot of road to travel just to use Socket::select.